# Dealing with excess coefficients in JPEG images

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, crop

All the info I've found about the JPEG standard specifies that data units should be 8x8, so I'm wondering what should be done in the event that a given picture's dimensions are not multiples of 8.

Take, for example, a 512x512 grayscale image: if I crop it to 508x508 (so as remove pixels from the top and the left) I'll have 16 coefficients that can't fit neatly into 8x8 data units. I guess I have to introduce some data units containing coefficients from the original image along with some filler 0s, and then trust the decoder on the other end to rely on the updated header info, so as to not display those 0s. Am I right, or am I looking at this the wrong way entirely?

What then happens if I want to crop a colour picture that uses, say, 4:2:0 chroma subsampling? Does it make any sense to "upsample" it to 4:4:4, do the crop, add those filler 0s, and then take it down to 4:2:0 again, essentially allowing the filler 0s to have an impact on the actual look of the image's right and bottom borders? Or in that event, am I better off using some sort of average value as filler?

Thanks!

Comment: The JPEG spec is clear that full MCUs must be encoded even if the image size is not an exact multiple of the MCU size. The unused pixels should be set to 0 or the DC value to minimize wasted bits in the output. If you're cropping the encoded data, it shouldn't be necessary to decode/desample and resample/recode it due to color subsampling.

Comment: @BitBank I think this comment deserves to be an answer, probably even the accepted one. I'd vote for it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPEG spec is clear that full MCUs (minimum coded units) must be encoded even if the image size is not an exact multiple of the MCU size. The unused pixels should be set to 0 or the DC value to minimize wasted bits in the output. If you're cropping the encoded data, it shouldn't be necessary to decode/desample and resample/recode it due to color subsampling. Here is an article which has more details about this topic:

http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-minimum-coded-unit.html

When cropping sub-sampled images, the same rules apply. Partial color and luma blocks should be handled the same way as a non sub-sampled image.